# index of /images script?

Tags: javascript, html

First of all im not even sure if what im looking for is even something that can be done.

I'm trying to see if its possible and if so where should I look to do it, to have a search bar on a page. in the search bar you would enter the index of the folder containing images for the different URL's entered in. after submitting the url have it add the image tag to anything with a .jpg, .png etc allowing you to see the images in the list instead of having to click on them one at a time.

I know this can be done on a page by page basis but as the URL changes and it is not on the same host, I dont know if its even something possible.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. You're going to need to add much more detail to your question to get a useful answer. What do you mean by "enter the index of the folder containing images for the different URLs entered in"? If you're asking if you can asynchronously load images via JS instead of just listing links to the images, yes this is certainly possible via the `img` tag to display any image(s).

Answer (score 1):

javascript is client based. any search done with javascript will only result in searching your client's computer not your server where your images will be hosted.

youre going to need to do this via server side languages like php

Comment: javascript can also be used server side

Comment: Since nodejs became a thing in 2009? https://nodejs.org/en/ - I’m not sure if you were joking or not.

Comment: the code run on a server is going to be run on the server, the code run on a client will be run on the client. Nice try though